# Finding the rate of change in direction

Tags: calculus, vectors

How would I go about answering this question? Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

> Find a unit vector in the direction in which $f$ increases most rapidly at $P$, and find the rate of change of $f$ at $P$ in that direction:
>   $$f(x,y) = \sqrt{\frac{xy}{x+y}}$$

Comment: Hint: read the section on "gradient" in your text. Maximum rate of increase is in the direction of gradient and the rate is the length or norm of gradient vector.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose we should point you in the direction of maximal increase?

At any rate, you're looking for the *gradient* of $f$; for any differentiable function $f$, $\nabla f$ (or grad$(f)$ if you prefer) points in the direction of maximal increase at any given point.

Answer (score 0):

Compute $\nabla f = \left({\partial f\over \partial x}, {\partial f\over\partial y}\right)$. This is a vector that points in the direction of fastest increase of $f$. Evaluate it at point $P$. Then normalize the vector to unit length (because they asked for a unit vector). The rate of change of $f$ in that direction is the dot product of $\nabla f$ with the unit vector.